# Can we get a paste feature added to image uploads in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, uploader

We've already got it for questions and answers. Let's get it for chat too! Most of my images come from screen captures so this would be really great!

[image: Uploader via Question/Answer]

[image: Uploader via Chat]

Comment: This is definitely on our list of things to do; we were mainly waiting on the code to stabilize before integrating it

Comment: Great to hear. I look forward to it!

Comment: Have some rep, Todders.

Comment: @MarcGravell any update on this? I'm just curious / anxiously waiting :)

Comment: @Todders did that not get done? Hmm... That's odd - will look into why... I thought we had them up to date with each other.

Comment: @MarcGravell Not that I can tell. I look forward to hearing what you find out!

Comment: @ToddersLegrande Now now, you don't reasonably expect something as complex as a picture upload script to become stable in a TINY little year do you??!?!

Comment: @MarcGravell Mick makes a good point. No rush on this. Sorry for being so impatient.

Comment: @MarcGravell Any update? This's integrated into the main site, but not chat. I find it a pain to save it to the desktop and then browse through all of my files and folders with the upload dialog to add an image in chat. As a moderator, this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we either get an ETA or a status as why this hasn't been done yet? It sounded like it was planned to be implemented but hasn't been. I hate to nag but I feel plenty of time has passed for me to question this again. Thank you!

Comment: I am in agreement with Spartan here. @MarcGravell is there any update on this?

Comment: @MarcGravell *"we were mainly waiting on the code to stabilize before integrating it"* - Has the code stabilized? Can the wait be over?

Comment: I recently added drag and drop and paste from clipboard for images to [Chat Dark Theme Plus](https://stackapps.com/questions/6619/chat-dark-theme-plus) chrome extension. Might be worth looking at for short-term solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Well for the time being I've signed up for the imgur api and created a tampermonkey / userscript for this. My code is included below.

## **If you use this make sure you update the URL you want to use this on as well as your own API key.**

Once you have this running on the chat room you wish to use it in it is simply a matter of clicking in the text box and pasting in image data. This script probably has flaws due to the fact that I just put it together based on several blogs and being a complete newbie to how userscripts work, etc. but it fits my needs for now.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       tehimgur
// @namespace  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development
// @version    0.1
// @match      http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development
// ==/UserScript==
function upload(file) {
    if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;

    document.body.className = "uploading";
        var text = document.getElementById("input").value
        document.getElementById("input").value = "Uploading...";
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.json");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var link = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link;
            document.getElementById("input").value = text + link;
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE');
    xhr.send(fd);
}

/* Handle paste events */
function pasteHandler(e) {
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        if (items) {
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") !== -1) {
                    var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                    upload(blob);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler);
```

Comment: Additionally, make sure your redirect URL is set to https://imgur.com (https) in your imgur app settings

Answer (score 3):

Can we do this without a dialog and a button ... just have the chat window accept image file drops or something ... would be much cooler :)