# Simplify image uploading process in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface

Pasting an image into chat should really be done in fewer steps than it is now. This is how it should work ideally:

1. Paste image from clipboard into chat text box [*like you can do in Q&A part of the site*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120943/add-an-image-directly-from-the-clipboard).
2. Press "Send".

Or if you copied the link to the image instead of the image itself:

1. Paste original image link into chat text box;
2. Press "Upload to imgur and post".

But I guess we're not getting that so easily, so instead a proposal to improve existing menus:

1. Press "Upload…" button;
2. Press Ctrl+V to paste a copied image link;
3. Press Enter to post.

For comparison, right now it's like so:

1. Press "Upload…" button;
2. Press "From the web" button;
3. Manually focus on the link input field (wtf?);
4. Press Ctrl+V to paste text;
5. Press Enter to post.

If this all is too hard to code right now (which shouldn't be), then at the very least, after pressing "From the web" button, the focus should automatically go to the link input field, which currently does not for some reason. Come on, guys, this is basic usability stuff :p

**Also:** right now posting an image using the "Upload…" button totally ignores the message id to which you are replying, so you have to edit the posted image to include the message id. This should also be accounted for when uploading to imgur and posting.

Comment: It would also be nice to have the ability to paste an actual image into the dialog, like is possible when posting a question or answer on the main sites.

Comment: Related (nearly duplicated): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173448/can-we-get-a-paste-feature-added-to-image-uploads-in-chat

Answer (score 1):

Great suggestion.

You should simply **drag** an image from your desktop, in to this text box one types in.

It's just that simple.

Anything else is 1950s style - really backwards and silly.

(At the moment BTW, if you drag a PNG in to this text box you just get...

/Users/fatster/Desktop/Useless example image 2014-10-24 at 16.31.58.png

)

Comment: Dragging is a lot less convenient than pasting.

Comment: Mini- if you suggest also having pasting, sure.  But "dragging something" is an incredibly basic metaphor on all modern platforms.

Comment: Well, the top of the question now asks for the ability to paste. (P.S. The way I have things set up, personally, it’s inconvenient for me to drag a local image, and it’s a modern platform, so, no, not all.)