# Why is there no image pasting functionality in chat rooms yet?

Tags: support, chat, images

I find it **extremely cumbersome & slow** to save images on my desktop or copy/paste screenshots into Paint to then save them, just to be able to send them to a user in chat.

It's particularly time-wasting when going back and forth with debugging screenshots for example, when dealing with Stack Overflow questions.

I'm aware of a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173448/1081259) that was asked 8 years ago regarding similar functionality, however, that question didn't really get an answer so based on general [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) & how long has passed without any updates, I think this question is more than relevant today, after 8 years.

Marc Gravell mentioned in the comments of that question:

> This is definitely on our list of things to do; we were mainly waiting on the code to stabilize before integrating it

Has the code stabilised yet?
Is there any ETA?
Are there any blockers?
Is it really difficult to make this improvement?

It shouldn't be a huge, mammoth task to allow users to directly copy and paste an image into a chat.

**Are we ever going to get this feature?**

Comment: It is possible to fix with an extension, the darkamode one I use has it

Comment: You might like the userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/6199/dragdrop-image-uploader-for-chat

Comment: Thanks, folks but - why can't it just be an in-built feature? If others can do it in a *user script*, it makes the feature even more trivial for SE to not implement.

Comment: I mean, that'd be great, but until then there's alternatives, ;)

Comment: @KevinB If I have to wait another 8 years, I'll leave it for my kids to chase up :))

Comment: This might have been better as a bounty on the old question

Comment: Image pasting was a relatively recent addition to the sites. Chat hasn't received much new feature development since the time before it was implemented on the sites.

Comment: If you've seen the Q4 roadmap, discovery on chat so we can finally start investing on improvements to it is on the roadmap. :)

Comment: @animuson Oh - do you have a link you could share please? I didn't find anything Googling

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I believe animuson means [this roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/09/19/the-loop-our-community-department-roadmap-for-q4-2021/)

Comment: I suspect I'll have a busy quarter suggesting all the stuff I'd love improved in chat. I only have a half decade long wishlist :D

Comment: To the extent that the question is why there the functionality isn't there: chat hasn't gotten much development work in years.

Comment: @RyanM Frankly? They were more focused on "shiner" projects with better ROI, and no one who wasn't deeply engaged in the communities got it. Its a testament to the robustness of how it was built in the first place that it runs fairly well, and a big showstopper for 'major' changes since most things that rely on it are based on UI that's not changed in a decade. I have a monumental rant on this waiting for the right moment :D